# Getting the response as PDF in browser

Tags: java, content-type

I want to setup response for PDF output. How do I achieve this?

I can setup for Excel output and successfully get the desired excel sheet from the browser, but for PDF I could not get the desired output.

For Excel the following code works fine

```
String excelContent = "an html table..";
getServletResponse().setContentType("“application/vnd.ms-excel");
getServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + pageTitle + ".xls");
PrintWriter ps = getServletResponse().getWriter();
ps.println(excelContent);
```

But for PDF I tried setting the content type to PDF, but could not get it properly (no content gets displayed even though a PDF file is opened in the browser)

```
String excelContent = "an html table..";
getServletResponse().setContentType("“application/pdf");
getServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + pageTitle + ".pdf");
PrintWriter ps = getServletResponse().getWriter();
ps.println(excelContent);
```

Do html tables cannot be displayed as such in PDF?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with the [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) renderer. It takes HTML input and returns PDF. What you have to do is to declare content type as PDF, generate HTML to a string, and call a method from Flying Saucer.

Here is an example 
[xhtml to pdf servlet with flyingsaucer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393142/xhtml-to-pdf-servlet-with-flyingsaucer)

Answer (score 0):

You are writing html context to the response stream. You need to write pdf format to the response.

You can use libraries like iText or Apache FOP to create PDF format.

Comment: Isn't there a simple way of sending the html response as PDF, is using those libraries the only way?

Comment: Not which I am aware of. You would need to use some or the other library. There are many options so you could google for simplest one to achieve this task if you do not need other advanced features.